# Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Failed to pull hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:1.4: API error (500) on Kubernetes multiple nodes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to run fabric network on kubernetes multiple node. The problem occurred while instantiating the chaincode. It works fine on single node Kubernetes cluster but gives following error on chaincode instantiation on multiple nodes.

**Error on Peer**

> 2020-12-01 11:15:29.083 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 32b
> [channel1][10d225ff] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error:
> Post
> http://docker:2375/build?networkmode=host&t=nid1-org1peer1-cc-1.0-bb7b63f343a13a21a9c1a0d74aa7d87a8898eaa0f093e1c77941b4fc795223f3b4: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Failed to pull
> hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:1.4: API error (500): Get
> https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while
> waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting
> headers)

**Error on docker-dind**

> time="2020-12-01T11:15:29.066402366Z" level=warning msg="Error getting
> v2 registry: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request
> canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while
> awaiting headers)" time="2020-12-01T11:15:29.066733856Z" level=info
> msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get
> https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while
> waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting
> headers)"

Answer (score 0):

When the fabric's chaincode is instantiated, it is created as a docker's container in the form of a sandbox.
The container above is created in a docker image called fabric-ccenv, which is defined in the peer's configuration (core.yaml).

When looking at the current log, it seems that the above image cannot be pulled.

It seems that it will be solved by executing the code below and downloading the image to the local repository.

```
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:1.4
```

In addition, the error appears to be a problem related to the docker's DNS/proxy, and I also had the same issue.

I fixed this by setting 8.8.8.8 as the default DNS

-> docker/Preferences/Proxies

- check `System proxy`

-> System Preferences

- Then, add my system DNS server `8.8.8.8`